# Removing trusted certificate from Mail in iOS 8

Tags: mail.app, ios, certificate

My IMAP (and SMTP) server used a self signed certificate.

Once I marked the certificate as "trusted" in the Mail app, is there a way to remove that trust again?

I tried deleting and re-creating the email account, but the certificate is still trusted afterwards.

The certificate does not show up in the Profiles section of the Settings app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might not have actually "trusted" it, but rather made "exception" for it as detailed here: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/

If you did import the certificate, then the above website shows how to remove the "profile" that contains the certificate. To remove the exception, it looks like you need to reset all settings (General > Reset > Reset Settings). Unfortunately it deletes all your settings.

There is further discussion here:

[How do you remove SSL certificate exceptions on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130612/how-do-you-remove-ssl-certificate-exceptions-on-ios)

Comment: Well, I the button I clicked on was labeled "trust", and also there is no practical distinction between trusting the certificate and "making an exception" for it, is there?
Anyway, I guess you are right about the reset. I will not test it, but I will mark your answer as accepted.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there is much difference, though the blogpost does point out that the exception only applies to the single application (Safari in the post example) and what is important to us, once the exception is accepted, you are pretty much stuck with it. I am going to have to do a better job with this type of thing for the next time I set up a server with a self-signed certificate. It looks like the "best practices" would be to create a self-signed certificate authority and then distribute THAT to everyone's devices.

Comment: The whole thing only comes up, because of a bug in iOS that won't let me install the CA root (in this case that of cacert.org, not self-signed) as trusted. see https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5347967917621248

Comment: This did not work for me on iOS 9