# URL not opening on iPhone 5s via Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, ipad

We are accessing an URL (`https://mobimytravel.wipro.com/APIMapper`) but it is not opening in iPhone 5s & iPad using Wi-Fi but the same URL is opening in 3G.

This URL is opening in Android & other different iOS phones using Wi-Fi.

[image: Error]

Comment: What version(s) of iOS is running on the devices that are having problems, and the devices that are not having the problems?

Comment: IPhone 5s version:8.1.2 is the version where the phone is not working & the Iphone version 7.0.4 where this link is working

Comment: Hi Tube please reply top most urgent..do i need to install any certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the accountservices.wipro.com site.

It looks like they certificate has expired.

> accountservices.wipro.com uses an invalid security certificate. The
>   certificate expired on 2/13/15, 3:59 PM. The current time is 2/15/15,
>   10:41 PM. (Error code: sec_error_expired_certificate)

What now? [see this....](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130626/46541)