# How do you remove SSL certificate exceptions on OS X?

Tags: macos, ssl

When connecting to a URL via HTTPS and the SSL certificate doesn't match (such as at a paid Wi-Fi hotspot), Safari shows a dialog asking whether the certificate should be accepted. If you accept the certificate, OS X adds an SSL exception and will never ask about that certificate again.

The question is, where is that exception stored? And how can I get rid of it?

Note that this question is essentially the OS X version of “[How do you remove SSL certificate exceptions on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130612/how-do-you-remove-ssl-certificate-exceptions-on-ios)”, however the iOS answers make no sense for OS X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exceptions are stored in Keychain Access. The certificate will be copied there, together with the trust settings. Double-click a certificate and you will be able to change it's settings. Note: you can have trust setting on system level and user level! They have separate keychains as listed in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks John. Do you know if deleting immediately makes a certificate stop working or does it require a restart? I'm testing the quality of our SSL certificates in Apple Mail.

Comment: Deleting or changing the trust settings take effect immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer didn't work for me. A method that work for me is to open the "Keychain Access" app (which can be found through Spotlight Search), then click the "Certificates" category. Then right-click on the certificate you want to delete and delete it.

Comment: For me also, only this answer works